# worklight embedded browser not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have worklight up and running with the "hello world" example running in a Linux environment using instructions from here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

But, I can't see the application design because worklight can't load the embedded browser:

[image: screenshot of worklight embedded browser error]

Clicking 'additional information' took me to another useless screen:

[image: 404 error upon clicking 'additional information']

So, then I pointed to an external browser (chrome in my case),
but still no result:

[image: failed external browser]

Then attempting to use the worklight 'console', yields this:

[image: nothing in the console]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/com.ibm.rad.worklight.doc/topics/trpebrowser_linux_xul.html) is what you need. You need to manually force a xulrunner version to use.

Comment: Thanks. Also just "sudo apt-get install libwebkit-1.0-0" solved the problem below.

Answer (score 0):

By "embedded browser" I'm guessing it is trying to open a browser window inside Eclipse...

You can go to Eclipse preferences and search for "web browser". There, change the default browser to your preferred external browser.

Next, or in addition, you can just right-click on the Worklight project and select "Open Worklight console". From there you can click on the "preview common resources" or the environment icon (if you added any) and preview.

Comment: My external browser is chrome - can worklight deal with that?

Comment: What is not working? Did you right-click the project and select "open worklight console"? If Eclipse cannot find your browser, then this is a system error not Worklight. Worklight is a plug-in that uses Eclipse...

Comment: You can also go to the console directly by navigating to http://localhost:10080/your-project-name/console - make sure your Worklight Development Server is up & running (go to the servers tab and verify that it is running, or click the 'play' icon to start it).

Comment: I'm not seeing any "preview common resources" in the console. (See above screenshot).

Isn't the whole point to have your changes reflected in a single Eclipse environment........ if I use the console, I have to deploy the app to test it, not see my results immediately.

Comment: If Eclipse cannot render your browser, I don't see how I can help you with that. The alternative is to use an external browser, which is a perfectly valid one in Worklight development and even more encouraged because then you also get the added value of the chrome dev tools, for example. As a web developer - you should want that.

Comment: As for not seeing anything, to me it looks more like you just didn't deploy your project, which again, is the expected action to do in Worklight development. Right-click on the app folder and select Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server. This is a MUST step. Now that Worklight Server is aware that you have an app... you can start making changes and just save w/out needing to re-deploy again; it should suffice to simply refresh the browser window to have them reflected.

Comment: OK, yes the preview worked from the instructions in: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_01_Creating_your_first_Worklight_application.pdf

But the document needs to be totally re-ordered. Running the preview should be moved to the beginning as soon as the hello-world example is created - not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has nothing to do with worklight: Eclipse doesn't just "dump" your external browser into an eclipse window.

It uses the webkit libraries to construct a browser frame inside eclipse so that you can interact with it.

For Linux users, you need to make sure the webkit libraries are installed correctly in Linux before Eclipse can discover and use them properly. Heres some instructions:

For me, this was as simple as

> sudo apt-get install libwebkit-1.0-0

Followed by restarting Eclipse.